# Better way to achieve this instead of Immediately Invoked Function Expression?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for better ways to achieve this. Any better way rather than using the IIFE assigned to `type`

```
inputSources: inputSources
    .map(({ _objectId, caption: inputCaption, lookupId, picklistId, type }) => ({ 
      _id: _objectId,
      caption: inputCaption,
      participantCriteriaId: _id,
      referenceId: (lookupId || picklistId) || null,
      type: (() => {
        if (type === 'identifier' && lookupId) return 'lookup';
        if (type === 'identifier' && !lookupId) return 'key';
        return type;
      })(),
    })),
```

> update: ESLint doesn't like nester ternary operator

Comment: Ternary expression?

Comment: `type: type === ('identifier' && lookupId) ? 'lookup' : 'key'`

Comment: You should post your question on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would probably add a helper function and call that. That increases readability: `type: getType(type, lookupId)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely would recommend a ternary operator, which is the most readable option here. (I'm happy to disagree with ESLint there).

But you can simply move the statement before the object literal:

```
inputSources.map(({ _objectId, caption: inputCaption, lookupId, picklistId, type }) => {
  if (type === 'identifier')
    type = lookupId ? 'lookup' : 'key';
  return { 
    _id: _objectId,
    caption: inputCaption,
    participantCriteriaId: _id,
    referenceId: lookupId || picklistId || null,
    type,
  };
}),
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I would like to close this question out. can you please delete the answer. I feel i should ask in codereview stack @bergi

Comment: @thegeekajay I think it's absolutely fine here. Still, you can flag it for moderator attention and ask it to be migrated (including all the answers).